# Getting pdf error when adding text to pdf using ColumnText.showTextAligned method of Itext 5.0 jar in java

Tags: java, itext

I need to add some text to pdf. I am doing this by creating a Phrase and passing it to ColumnText.showTextAligned method and there is just one specific pdf which gives an error when the pdf is viewed:-
"An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person...
"
Below is the code snipped that is being used to add text:-

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfBytes);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, pdfOutputByteArray);
            PdfContentByte page;
            FontSelector selector = new FontSelector();
            int start = 0;
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("GARABD.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            Font font1 = new Font(bf, 12, Font.NORMAL);
            selector.addFont(font1);

            for (int i = start; i < n + start; i++) {
                page = stamper.getOverContent(i - start + 1);
                Rectangle rect = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i - start + 1);
                page.beginText();
                page.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
                page.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);

                    Phrase ph = selector.process(staticText);
                    ColumnText.showTextAligned(page, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, ph, rect.getRight(350), rect.getTop(60), 0);

                page.endText();
            }
```

When I try to add the same text by the below method no error comes up, below is the code:-

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfBytes);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, pdfOutputByteArray);
    PdfContentByte page;
    FontSelector selector = new FontSelector();
    int start = 0;
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("GARABD.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font1 = new Font(bf, 12, Font.NORMAL);
    selector.addFont(font1);

    for (int i = start; i < n + start; i++) {
        page = stamper.getOverContent(i - start + 1);
        Rectangle rect = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i - start + 1);
        page.beginText();
        page.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
        page.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);


            page.setTextMatrix(rect.getRight(455), rect.getTop(60));
            page.showText(staticText);


        page.endText();
```

I would like to mention that this is happening for just one particular pdf of one page. Below is the pdf link:-

Download Link: https://www.send18.com/?uid=a89d-403ee175
Password: 9mbBvqwY

The code can't be changed because it has been written at many places, moreover changing the code for just one pdf doesn't make sense.
Please advise what can be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two different things.

You can either have this:

```
page.beginText();
page.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
page.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
page.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, "some text", x, y, 0);
page.endText();
```

Or you can have this:

```
Phrase ph = new Phrase("some text");
ColumnText.showTextAligned(page, Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, ph, x, y, 0);
```

The latter is shorthand for the former.

`ColumnText.showTextAligned()` creates a `beginText()` and `endText()` internally, so you have something like:

```
page.beginText();
page.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
page.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
page.beginText();
page.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
page.showTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, "some text", x, y, 0);
page.endText();
page.endText();
```

It's illegal in PDF to nest text objects and that is what's causing the error.

I advise that you remove the following lines form your code:

```
page.beginText();
page.setFontAndSize(bf, 12);
page.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);

page.endText();
```

This should solve the problem.

You say that you can't change the code, but you should. Right now *all* the PDFs you are creating are wrong. The error is ignored in most cases, but there's no guarantee that the error will be ignored by (all versions of) all PDF viewers.

Comment: Thanks so much @Bruno. You are exactly right. It works now. Since the existing code is wrong, will have to change the code!